# Trigonometrical relation (searching a easy way to see it).

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the figure I want to know $cos(\phi)$. I only know the cosines $cos(\theta)$ and $cos(\eta)$. A is in the xy plane. [image]

I can do it using a bunch of trigonometrical relations (for example building a tetrahedron) but I think there must be a more straightful way to solve it. The result I get is $cos(\phi)=cos(\theta) cos(\eta)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C$ be placed on the $x$-axis such that $AC\perp OC$.

Thus, since also $OC\perp AB$, we obtain $OC\perp(ABC)$, which says $OC\perp BC$.

From here we get $\cos\varphi=\cos\theta\cos\eta$ immediately:
$$\cos\varphi=\frac{OC}{OB}=\frac{AO}{OB}\cdot\frac{OC}{OA}=\cos\theta\cos\eta.$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let $|OB|=1$. Then

from $\triangle BOA$: $|OA|=\cos\theta$,

from $\triangle BOC$: $\cos\phi=|OC|$,

from $\triangle AOC$: $|OC|=|OA|\cos\eta=\cos\theta\cos\eta$.